# variable size array in a FlowPane

Tags: java, javafx-2, fxml

If i have an array of variable size (for example a array of cards).

How can i build something to show the elements(in a FlowPane for example) and each of them having its own controller (fxml + controller for each card), so the container (flow pane) of the elements (cards) can have it's elements swaped, removed or added new ones?

Controller:

```
public class HandController extends FlowPane implements Initializable{
    @Override public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1){
    }
    public void setHand(ArrayList<Cards> Hand){
        //this would work if the hand were static
        for(int i = 0; i < Hand.size(); ++i){
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("CardView.fxml"));
            CardController controller = new CardController();
            fxmlLoader.setController(controller);
            fxmlLoader.setRoot(controller);
            Parent card = (Parent)fxmlLoader.load();
            fxmlLoader.setRoot(card);
            this.getChildren().add(card);
            controller.setCard(Hand.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Fxml:

```
<fx:root type="FlowPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
         stylesheets="view/Style.css">
    <children>
        <!--should i put something here?-->
    </children>
</fx:root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FXML is static language (at least for now). It describes static page.

If you want to have dynamic content you need to code it.

For example you can introduce methods in your controller which will perform operations with cards and call these methods then appropriate. Fixed a bit your code as well.

```
<!-- HandView.fxml -->
<fx:root type="FlowPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" stylesheets="view/Style.css">
  <children>
    <!-- just leave it emtpy -->
  </children>
</fx:root>
```

HandController:

```
public class HandController extends FlowPane {

 HandController() {
   FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("HandView.fxml"));
   fxmlLoader.setController(this);
   fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
   fxmlLoader.load();
 }

 public void setHand(ArrayList<Cards> hand){
    for(int i = 0; i < hand.size(); ++i){
        addCard(hang.get(i));
    }    
 }

 public void addCard(Cards card) {
    getChildren().add(new CardController(card));
 }
}
```

put all CardController initialization in the constructor:

```
public class CardController extends Pane {
 private final Card card;
 CardController(Card card) {
   this.card = card;
   FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("CardView.fxml"));
   fxmlLoader.setController(this);
   fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
   fxmlLoader.load();
 }
}
```

Comment: I see, thank you very much, so every time I do anything with the hand, I have to call the `setHand()`? (would be nice if could be done automatically like the TableView with its `ObserbableList`)

Comment: if you change `setHand()` parameter to ObservableList and add correspondent listeners you can achieve automation.

Comment: so in `setHand()` i should add a listener on the ObserbableList for whenever the list size is affected so can update the cards on the controller with the `setHand()` we have now(maybe call it `updateHand()` now)?

Comment: why rename? `setHand(ObsevableList<Card> hand)` will connect HandController with a `hand` object. It's one time operation.

Comment: oh yes, sorry, did not notice that, although still not really sure on how to build this other version with listener and ObservableList (since have to create a new CardController when adding a card or remove it when a card is removed)

Comment: just add/remove controllers in listener